# Titanium Table view with Switch box in android causes problem while Scrolling?

Tags: android, titanium

I Create the Table View ,each row will contain Text and checkbox loaded the row with values from Database, where i set some checkbox in default true and remaining are false, but when i scroll the checkbox are selected in default where i set it as false, while scrolling only the problem occur, i don`t know how to solve that.

This is the code i use.

i also tried instead of setting default values for checkbox , i initialized all checkbox as false, while selecting any check box on runtime and scroll down some other text box at also selected, it is occur only while scrolling , i don`t know how to solve this issues, if any one knows means help me out.

```
function setArray(){                
            var db = Ti.Database.install('../databases/ChecklistDB.sqlite','ChecklistDB');
            var rows = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT category, defaultCheck FROM revcheck ORDER BY id');              
            var dataArray = [];         
            while (rows.isValidRow())
            {                   
                var bgcolor = 'black';
                var fontColor = 'white';                                    
                dataArray.push({
                    title: rows.fieldByName('category'),
                    check: rows.fieldByName('defaultCheck'),
                hasChild:true,           
                backgroundColor:bgcolor,
                color:fontColor,                    
                font:{fontSize:'12dp',fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue',fontWeight:'bold'}, 
                path:'../scripts/Contents.js'

                });
                rows.next();    
            }
            dataItems = [];
            //var checkbox=[];              
                for (var i =0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();             
                var lblTitle = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text:dataArray[i].title,
                left:40                     
                });

                    var checkbox= Titanium.UI.createSwitch({
                    style:Titanium.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,    
                    ret:dataArray[i].title,
                    left:0
                        }); 


                    if(checkbox.ret=='Metadata'){
                         checkbox.value = true;
                    }           
                     else{
                        checkbox.value = false;
                     }
                var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
                image:'../images/arrows.png',
                left:270                    
                }); 
                button.addEventListener('click', function(){
                var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                url:'../scripts/Contents.js',               
                fullscreen: false
                }); 
                    win.open();
                });


                row.add(lblTitle);
                row.add(checkbox);
                row.label = lblTitle;                   
                //row.checkbox = checkbox;
                row.add(button);
                row.button = button;
                row.className = 'ContentsRow';
                dataItems.push(row);


                }   
            tableview.setData(dataItems);


        }

        var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({
            backgroundColor:'black',
            backgroundSelectedColor:'#12A1FF',                  
            top:'2%',
            left:0,
            height:'95%',
            width:'100%'                
        }); 

        setArray();
```

Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting the className property on the tables. also what version of the SDK are you using.